# Connect non-domain PC to Lync 2013 (AddressBook Issue so far)

Tags: domain, lync

I'm setting up Lync 2013 Standard Edition in my Lab and want to test it's features and its compatibility.
I have managed to successfully install Lync 2013 Standard Edition, create some users and SIP enable them. I have setup Lync 2013 Clients (Domain-member PCs) to connect to server. They can IM each other fine.

I have also installed Lync Client on a non-domain computer, installed root CA certificate, DNS is good. I can log in to Lync, but I cannot search for any users by their first/last name.

***"Address Book Synchronizing, Results may not be current"***

I can only search the users by their SIP name.
Whereas from domain-joined computer, I can search and find this user with first/last name just fine.

I would appreciate if you could shed some lights on where i'm doing something wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Did you configure and publish External Web Services in your Lync Topology ? e.g : what's the output for `Get-CsService -WebServer | FL ExternalFQDN` from your Front-End Server ?

Comment: I'm testing this inside the LAN, so I haven't got to the External Part Yet. Actually I had to wait a hour or two, then the client on non-domain computer could search for the users.

Comment: New installs of the Lync client do not immediately download the address book.  To force the client to update immediately, add this registry key:
2010:
    reg add HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Communicator /v GalDownloadInitialDelay /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
2013 (x86):
reg add HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Communicator /v GALDownloadInitialDelay /t REG_DWORD /d 0
2013 (x64):
reg add HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Communicator /v GALDownloadInitialDelay /t REG_DWORD /d 0

Answer (score 0):

A Lync client do not directly download the Adressbook. It can take some time until this happen. You can change the registry in order to do that:

> reg add HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync
>   /v GalDownloadInitialDelay /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

Microsoft has a wonderful [TechNet documentation which explains that in more details](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rischwen/2014/03/10/lync-2013-force-address-book-download-registry-keys/).